# Sencha GXT NumberInputCell length

Tags: gwt, gxt

So I need to make custom number cell with limitation 20 digits before comma and 16 decimal digits after comma. 
Tried to override `onKeyDown()` but it doesn't check typed value dynamically, only value before blur. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.form.NumberInputCell;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.NumberField;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor;

public class NumberFieldTest implements EntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {

    IntegerPropertyEditor integerEditor = new IntegerPropertyEditor();

    NumberInputCell<Integer> numberFieldCell = new NumberInputCell<Integer>(integerEditor) {
      @Override
      protected void onKeyPress(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Element parent, Integer value,
          NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<Integer> valueUpdate) {          
        super.onKeyPress(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdate);

        String textValue = getInputElement(parent).getValue();
        if (textValue != null && textValue.length() > 3) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    };

    NumberField<Integer> numberField = new NumberField<Integer>(numberFieldCell, integerEditor);

    RootPanel.get().add(numberField);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that kinda OK solution. For field. Not cell. Because cell can be used inside some kind of grid and validation should be attached exactly to cell.

Comment: Ah, I quickly read. I've changed the example to show how you could do it in the cell.